# "Error '424' Object required" when trying to display "Temp.jpg" in an Image Box (imgRpts1)

Tags: excel, vba, image, controls, box

The `Application` I am working on `Runs` in front of the `Excel Workbook` so the `User` has NO direct access to the individual `Worksheets`. The primary area of concern is with the `Reports Worksheets` where I want to `Display` the equivalent of a `Print Preview` of the `Worksheet` with all the `data` populated on the `Worksheet`. I have 4 `ComboBoxes configured as DDLs` and a `Submit Button` implementing the functionality of selecting the desired `Worksheet`, the `Named Ranges` associated with the respective `Worksheets`, and populating the appropriate `cells` on those `Worksheets`(See Image Below).
[image: Form Controls]
**ALL** `Variables` for `Worksheets` and `Ranges` are `Declared` as `Global Variables` in the `WB_Initialization` `Module` and `Set` in `UserForm_Initialize()`!

The `Choose Report Type` `ComboBox Change Event` sets the `ActiveWorksheet` and the remaining 3 `ComboBoxes` control the `values` that the `Worksheet` uses to implement proper selection and display of data, and the `Submit` populates the `Cells` on the `Worksheet` and calls the `Function` `DisplayRange rngToDisplay`! I confirmed proper operation of **ALL** `Worksheets` before implementing `DisplayRange rngToDisplay`!
The `Code` for `Choose Report Type` is as follows:

```
   Private Sub cmbPropWksts_Change() 'Located on MultiPage1.Page4
   Select Case cmbPropWksts.ListIndex
    Case 0
        wkstSum.Select
        rngRptSum.Select
        Set rngToDisplay = rngRptSum
    Case 1
        wkstDetail.Select
        rngRptDetail.Select
         Set rngToDisplay = rngRptDetail
    Case 2
        wkstCmpYrsElec.Select
        rngRptCmpYrsElect.Select
        Set rngToDisplay = rngRptCmpYrsElect
    Case 3
        wkstCmpYrsGas.Select
        rngRptCmpYrsGas.Select
        Set rngToDisplay = rngRptCmpYrsGas
   End Select

   cmdSubmit.Caption = "Display " & cmbPropWksts.Value

   Call MeasureSelection_Pixels

    If cmbPropWksts.ListIndex > 1 Then
        cmbwkstYrs2.Visible = True
    End If
    
   End Sub
```

The `Submit Button Code` is Here:

```
    
    pID = cmbRptPrpID.Text
    pIndex = cmbRptPrpID.ListIndex + 2
    wsYr1 = cmbWkstYrs1.Text
    wsYr2 = cmbwkstYrs2.Text
    
    Select Case cmbPropWksts.ListIndex
        Case 0
            ActiveSheet.Cells(3, "B") = cmbRptPrpID.Text              'Cell B3 of the Summary Worksheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells(3, "Q") = cmbWkstYrs1.Text              'Cell Q3 of the Summary Worksheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "A") = wsCntrl.Cells(pIndex, "N")    'Cell for the Property's address
        Case 1
            ActiveSheet.Cells(3, "B") = cmbRptPrpID.Text              'Cell B3 of the Summary Worksheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells(3, "Q") = cmbWkstYrs1.Text              'Cell Q3 of the Summary Worksheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "A") = wsCntrl.Cells(pIndex, "N")    'Cell for the Property's address
        Case 2, 3
            ActiveSheet.Cells(2, "B") = cmbRptPrpID.Text              'Cell B3 of the Summary Worksheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells(2, "C") = cmbWkstYrs1.Text              'Cell Q3 of the Summary Worksheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells(17, "C") = cmbwkstYrs2.Text             'Cell Q17 of the Summary Worksheet
            ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "A") = wsCntrl.Cells(pIndex, "N")    'Cell for the Property's address
    End Select
    
    
    DisplayRange rngToDisplay
    
    End Sub
```

And finally, `DisplayRange` Code is here:

```
        Function DisplayRange(r As Range)
        Dim wsChart As Worksheet
        Dim fname As String
        
        Set wsChart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tmpChart")
        
        fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TempImages\temp.jpg"
        
        r.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
        
        With wsChart
        Dim chtObj As ChartObject
        Set chtObj = .ChartObjects.Add(100, 30, 400, 250)
        
        With chtObj
            .Width = r.Width: .Height = r.Height
            .Chart.Paste
            .Chart.Export Filename:=fname, FilterName:="jpg"
            .Delete
        End With
        DoEvents
        End With
        
        imgRpts1.Picture = LoadPicture(fname)
        
        End Function
```

The `Call` to the above `Function` properly generates the `Chart` on the proper `Worksheet` as confirmed here:
[image: Image from tmpChart Worksheet]
And creates the `temp.jpg` image here:
[image: temp.jpg]
in the proper `Folder` here:
[image: TempImages Folder]
the `Error 424` happens here!
[image: Error 424]

My research indicates that the most common cause of this `Error` is due to `Undeclared/Improperly Declared Varables`! I have checked the `Varable Scopes`, `Image Box Name`, and the `File Paths` so apparently I am missing something.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: When stopped on error and moving the cursor over `imgRpts1` what does it display? Isn't `imgRpts1` `Nothing`? Please, place before the problematic line the next debugging one: `Debug.print imgRpts1 is Nothing: Stop` What does it return in Immediate Window, when code stops on this line? `True` or `False` for the object evaluation?

Comment: Have you used `Option Explicit` at the start of each module? My money is on the spelling of your ImageBox object - perhaps it should be imgRptS1 for example. Also, I don't see your Load picture function.

Comment: @Ambie, I copied the `(NAME) Property` from the `Properties Panel` for `imgRpts1` so I know the spelling is correct.  I did not use `Option Explicit` and that was an `oversight` on my part.

Comment: I had a similar problem, that I never solved, a couple months ago when I attempted to move `Sub-Routines` from the `UserForm` and gave up trying figure out why I kept getting `Variable Not Defined Errors` when I attempted to reference an object on the `UserForm`. I suspecct that adding 2 lines of `Code` to the `Function` in question, a `Dim` and `Set` line  this will resolve the issue of `Module` to `UserForm` communication and is likely a `2-minute Fix`. IF it does, I'll have answered my own question and will update with an `Answer of my own! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat as a result of a question from @Ambie, I revisited the `Module Code` for `Function DisplayRange`. I remembered a similar problem I had when trying to to move `Code` from the `UserForm` to a `Module` and kept getting a `Variable Not Defined Error`. I learned two valuable lessons today. First, Make sure to use `Option Explicit` in EVERY `Module`. Second I learned how to set up `Inter-Module` and `Module to UserForm` communication.

I resolved the issue by add these 2 lines of `Code`:

```
   Dim imgRpts1 As Object
   Set imgRpts1 = UserForm1.imgRpts1
```

Here is the final `Function Code`:

```
     Option Explicit
            
    Function DisplayRange(r As Range)
        Dim wsChart As Worksheet
        Dim fname As String
        Dim imgRpts1 As Object
        Set imgRpts1 = UserForm1.imgRpts1
        Set wsChart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tmpChart")
        fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TempImages\temp.jpg"
        
        r.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
        
        With wsChart
        Dim chtObj As ChartObject
        Set chtObj = .ChartObjects.Add(100, 30, 400, 250)
        
        With chtObj
            .Width = r.Width: .Height = r.Height
            .Chart.Paste
            .Chart.Export Filename:=fname, FilterName:="jpg"
            .Delete
        End With
        DoEvents
        End With
        
        imgRpts1.Picture = LoadPicture(fname)
    
    End Function
```

**AND IT WORKS!**
[![AND IT WORKS!][1]][1]
[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DfCD.jpg